# NSTokenField - read only but draggable tokens

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, readonly, nstokenfield

I have a XIB file which contains `NSTokenField`, i am adding tokens programatically.

I would like the `NSTokenField` to be read only (not editable) but still allow the user to rearrange the tokens by drag and drop.

I have tried to change the Behavior in the attributes editor from: "Editable" to: "Selectable", though it wont allow the user to edit, i am loosing the ability to drag and drop tokens inside the `NSTokenField`.

Do you have any idea how to accomplish a NSTokenField with draggable tokens but still not editable by the user?

Thanks in advance,

BR,
Mefuzar

Comment: Did you try implementing delegate method `control:textShouldBeginEditing:`?

Comment: Hi, I did try to subclass NSTokenField and override textShouldBeginEditing, though I didn't know how to block regular user editing over there and allow tokens drag and drop..  any clues?

Comment: I tried to find a way to switch editable on for drag & drop but I can't find a reliable way to switch editable off. It might be possible using method swizzling but I don't like swizzling.

Answer (score 1):

Set "Behavior" to "Selectable" in interface builder (or isSelectable = true, isEditable = false programatically).